# Unable to check ETCD cluster health

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, etcd

After following official guidance from (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/setup-ha-etcd-with-kubeadm/) for HA external ETCD, I was trying to check etcd cluster health status, but, it threw some error which I'm struggling to solve. Please help.

**Command used to check etcd cluster health that threw an error**:

```
docker run --rm -it \
--net host \
-v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0 etcdctl \
--cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt \
--key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key \
--cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
--endpoints https://${HOST0}:2379 endpoint health --cluster
```

Three bare-metal hosts, all ufw enabled, 2379 and 2380 ports allowed on entire hosts.

**Error**:

`````
Error: failed to fetch endpoints from etcd cluster member list: context deadline exceeded ```

**etcd docker image**:
``` k8s.gcr.io/etcd     3.4.3-0             303ce5db0e90        9 months ago        288MB ````
`````

Comment: That "context deadline" business also happens when etcd does not trust the certs; you'll also want to ensure it's in v3 mode by including `-e ETCDCTL_API=3` on your `run` command, and you may enjoy adding `--debug` or `-e ETCDCTL_DEBUG=true` to get a little more verbosity out of it

Answer (score 2):

`Context deadline exceeded` is an unclear error returned by grpc client when it can't establish the connection. you can set `ETCDCTL_API=2`, then you can get the right error message.
Also, you can change some code in etcd to debug this error.
see [#10087](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/10087)

You can solve this issue  when I applied the right cert/key pair.

Assuming you're using  `kubeadm`  to spin up the cluster, there should be a couple of cert/key pairs under the folder:

```
# ls -l /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/
total 32
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1017 Nov 12 15:32 ca.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1679 Nov 12 15:32 ca.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1094 Nov 12 15:32 healthcheck-client.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1675 Nov 12 15:32 healthcheck-client.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1180 Nov 12 15:32 peer.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1675 Nov 12 15:32 peer.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1180 Nov 12 15:32 server.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1679 Nov 12 15:32 server.key

# etcdctl --version
etcdctl version: 3.3.1
API version: 2

# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot save snapshot.db \
  --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
  --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
  --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
Snapshot saved at snapshot.db

# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --write-out=table snapshot status snapshot.db
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|   HASH   | REVISION | TOTAL KEYS | TOTAL SIZE |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| b9d500f7 |    72966 |       1194 |     4.9 MB |
```

You can also try to follow this instruction [error-context-deadline-exceeded-accessing](https://medium.com/@shoaibjdev/etcdctl-error-context-deadline-exceeded-accessing-etcd-control-in-newer-versions-of-kubernetes-ef78c83be6ce).

Take a look: [context-deadline-exceeded](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/10642#issuecomment-554297207).